# How to automigrate when needed in loopback 3?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I created an automigrate script under /bin in my loopback app and added its path in the package.json file so that I can run this script to automigrate whenever I want from the terminal.

I also have a boot script "createUsers.js" which creates some default users in a model. The problem is, whenever I run this script it calls the boot script and it tries to create the users while automigration is still not finished, resulting in a failed automigration. I don't understand why the boot scripts are called when I only run automigrate script specifically. I could call automigrate in the boot scripts and wrap the createUsers.js code in its callback (as shown [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/issues/109)), but that would automigrate every time the app is started which is undesirable since the data is lost on automigration. Where should I call automigrate() so that it can be called whenever required? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do, is create a script called util.js inside boot

util.js

```
class util{

    static _automigrate(){
          //Whatever you need to do
    }
}

module.exports = function (server) {
    global.util = util;
};
```

This way your script is available across the entire application. And you can call it whenever you need to.

You could call it with

```
util._automigrate();
```

I normally use this pattern to store all my input validations etc since I might need those across different models.